# How can centralised mapping logic from Entity to DTO be implemented in EF Core without performance suffering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In my domain I have defined an entity Person

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Tag { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Notes { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

and in my application layer I have a shallow DTO which I use to embed in reponses of which I can be certain that the user will query the details if I do not embed them:

```
public class PersonDetailsShallow
{
    public string PersonId { get; internal set; } = null!;
    public string Tag { get; internal set; } = null!;
}
```

Since the mapping from `Person` to `PersonDetailsShallow` happens in various places, I created a static helper function for that:

```
public static PersonDetailsShallow ToPersonDetailsShallow(this Person person)
{
    return new PersonDetailsShallow()
    {
        PersonId = person.Id,
        Tag = person.Tag
    };
}
```

---

Then, whenever I need a shallow person, I create it as follows:

```
// using MediatR;

public async Task<MediatorResult<List<PersonDetails>>> Handle(AllPersonsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;

    return dbContext.Persons
        .Select(p => p.ToPersonDetailsShallow())
        .ToList();
}
```

EF core however does not/ cannot recognise that the mapper function makes no use of `Person.Notes` and pulls it from the database by issuing the following query:

```
SELECT "p"."id", "p"."notes", "p"."tag"
FROM "persons" AS "p"
```

instead of issuing the more efficient query

```
SELECT "p"."id", "p"."tag"
FROM "persons" AS "p"
```

when doing the mapping like this:

```
var allPersons = dbContext.Persons
    .Select(p => new PersonDetailsShallow()
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Tag = p.Tag
    })
    .ToList();
```

However, since I am using PersonDetailsShallow in so many different places, it would become a maintenance-nightmare if anything ever changes in the entity `Person`, because I would have the same mapping logic all over the place.

*How can I have the benefit of maintaining the mapping logic in one place only while also getting the benefit of having optimised queries as I would when putting the mapping logic all over the place?*

---

I am aware that I could just create a separate query that fetches exactly the information needed to create a `PersonDetailsShallow` and return it, but then, if for example I have a set of collection of `PurchaseDetails`-DTOs, each of which I would want to embed a `PersonDetailsShallow`, then I would need to query the `PersonDetailsShallow` for each `PurchaseDetail`s separately, taking EF Core the possibility obtain all required data with one single query.

There must be some method `UseMapping(person => new PersonDetailsShallow() {...})` that I am missing, where I can provide the mapping function as a parameter or something.

Comment: `IQuerable<T>.Select()` takes an `Expression<T>` argument. You could define the expression in a static variable... Or define an extension methods `IQueryable<PersonDetailsShallow> AsShallow(IQueryable<Person> query)`?

Comment: Thank you both, that helped me to figure it out and I will write a self-answer in a bit.